# Can I switch scenes by swipe gesture or drag？

Tags: cocos2d

Can I switch scenes by swipe gesture or drag?

In my game, there are three main scenes, each of them has several layers which have some UI elements, these elements have some tap gesture.

[image]

I already know some ways to switch scenes, such as `replaceScene`, or by some transitions ways, just like `CCTransitionMoveInT`, so swiping scenes is feasible or not?

If not, why?

If yes, is it possible to cause memory increases that my gameApp crash?

Comment: Like, how you change screens for apps so at some point you can see half of both scenes at once? Or if you swipe it switches to a different scene? The latter is easy, maybe, the former not so much, at least not in anyway I'm aware of.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,Tony.My situation is the former.Unfortunately, just like what you said, till now, I cannot find a solution to this question.Replacing scenes has it's own way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [CCScrollLayer](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/tree/master/Extensions/CCScrollLayer) class from [cocos2d-iphone-extensions project](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions). It does exacactly what you want except for the scene changing part. Though you don't really need to change scenes here, a single scene with multiple layers works just as well.

Comment: YES!CCScrollLayer does works, maybe i really don't need to change scenes here.